# Collage of elements rising up (how do I do it)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Does anyone know how I can do this on my own site? (vuejs)
https://cdn.larkx.xyz/kv2bos6i.gif or https://sparkedhost.com

Comment: Please elaborate your question by asking something precise and not how to copy a website. The effect shown in the gif file seems related to CSS more than Vue.js

Comment: Tf? "Copy a website"? Mate... I asked how to create the same sort of effect where a collage of divs float up... How can I elaborate on that?

Comment: Ok I admit I was a bit rough here ;-) Sorry buddy
With your details it is more clear.

Comment: it's okay aha, I was too

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put Vuejs aside because this effect can be achieved with CSS only.

You can give a look at the source code of sparkedhost.com for a better understanding of how they implemented this effect, and here is an example of such effect without any embellishment:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  
}

.content {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scrolling {
  position: relative;

  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }

  to {
    top: -500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrolling">
    <div class="content" style="background-color: yellow;">#1</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: gray;">#2</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">#3</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: orange;">#4</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: green;">#5</div>
    <!-- The same block of divs is repeated -->
    <div class="content" style="background-color: yellow;">#1</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: gray;">#2</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">#3</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: orange;">#4</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: green;">#5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm assuming then it's just a matter of animation speed and columns to make it similar to sparkedhost